# How can you add a subtitle track dynamically to a video.js video player

Tags: javascript, html, video.js, subtitle

That's pretty much it; I need to change the subtitles to the theater of a webpage and if possible, even not have them at all, but mostly I wanna change the subtitles of a videojs player. I could show you the website but don't think it's necessary. I've tried:

```
videojs(theater_video, {tracks: `<track kind='subtitles' src='/resources/videos/whale_Shailene/Spanish.vtt' srclang='es' label='Español' ></track>
                                 <track kind='subtitles' src='/resources/videos/whale_Shailene/Arabic.vtt' srclang='ar' label='عرب.' ></track>`})
```

, and:

```
videojs(theater_video, {tracks: [{
         src: '/resources/videos/whale_Shailene/Spanish.vtt',
         kind:'subtitles',
         srclang: 'es',
         label: 'Español'
      },{
         src: '/resources/videos/whale_Shailene/Arabic.vtt',
         kind:'subtitles',
         srclang: 'ar',
         label: 'عرب.'
      }]})
```

But neither seem to appear nor even change the subtitles of the player

Neither a combination of either of those with:

```
$("#theater video").find("source").after(`<track kind='subtitles' src='/resources/videos/whale_Shailene/Spanish.vtt' srclang='es' label='Español' ></track>
                                          <track kind='subtitles' src='/resources/videos/whale_Shailene/Arabic.vtt' srclang='ar' label='عرب.' ></track>`)
```

I'm using Video.js v4.9.1 :/ And it seems like a tou[gh up](https://lirilc.github.io/whale_Shailene)date because I edited a lot the Video.js css and js files directly

Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option works, as a setup option. If you use that on a player that has already initialised, it does nothing. You can use `addRemoteTextTrack()` to add a track to a player. See https://videojs.com/guides/text-tracks

```js
videojs.getPlayer('theater_video').addRemotetextTrack({
  src: '/resources/videos/whale_Shailene/Spanish.vtt',
  kind:'subtitles',
  srclang: 'es',
  label: 'Español'
});
```

Comment: ```videojs('theater_video').player().L.addTextTrack``` is a function; neither ```videojs.getPlayer``` nor ```videojs('theater_video').player().addRemotetextTrack``` are functions. I edited the question to explain that I am a little outdated

Comment: It worked for me, that option, indeed as a setup option and had to change everything a bit. Thanks